# Measuring NodeJS memory usage for a single process

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, memory

I'd like to be able to see the amount of memory used by a single process. We've got some candidate libraries to be used in our application, and we'd like to perform a memory test to see how well every library performs.

Actually, I've looked for the net and I've found the `process.memoryUsage()` utility, but this is giving me inconsistent results:

```
console.log(process.memoryUsage());
for (let i = 0; i < 5000; i += 1) {
  await library.methodToBeUsed();
}
console.log(process.memoryUsage());
```

Logic says that this should begin with lower values and increase those values when the other process finishes, but the result is as follows:

```
// First console.log
{
    rss: 102670336,
    heapTotal: 77803520,
    heapUsed: 53179464,
    external: 5351574
}

// Second console.log
{
    rss: 77381632,
    heapTotal: 49864704,
    heapUsed: 45468016,
    external: 4326686
}
```

As you can see, the first `console.log` gives usage values higher than the second one. I can guess why is this happening, and it's because there are more processes in the background that also use memory and get executed, freed and so on during the execution of my process, but this code has been executed in a test jest file to try to avoid as much as possible the execution of unneeded parallel threads and processes.

Because of this, I'm wondering **how can I measure how well a library (or a precise piece of code) performs as per memory usage?**

*I've been unable to find any packages that help me do this (as all use the same approach I did).*

If you need any further information that I've missed, let me know.